# jQuery focus() and focusout() conflict in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Not sure how to solve this.

I'm using `jQuery.focus()` and `jQuery.focusout()` to trigger an Ajax request and rename a post in WordPress. This code works ok in Chrome and Firefox but i can't get it to work on IE.

snippet:

```
$('.editname').on('click', function() {

    var input = $('<input id="editcat" type="text" name="editcat" value="' + name + '" />');
    input.appendTo($(this));
    $("#editcat").focus();
});

$(".editname").focusout(function() {

    $(this).children('input').detach();
    $(this).children('span').show();


});
```

**working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/moraleida/fE5Tq/3/

Seems that focusout() event is called right after the `appendTo` in IE, before the browser has time to `focus()` on the appended input.

Is there a known workaround for this?

**EDIT**

Changing `focusout` to `blur` doesn't work. Apparently, the problem is that calling `$("#editcat").focus();` makes `.editname` loose focus/blur. If I comment that line, the input appears ok, but when I click to focus on it, it gets detached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was on attaching `focusout` to the parent element, instead of the `input` element. This solved it:

```
$(".editname").on('focusout', 'input', function() {

    // $(this) now refers to the input element, not .editname
    $(this).siblings('span').show();
    $(this).detach();


    });
});​
```

Final working fiddle for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/moraleida/fE5Tq/8/

Answer (score 2):

Try the blur event instead

```
$(".editname").on('blur', function() {

    $(this).children('input').detach();
    $(this).children('span').show();


});
```

Comment: Thanks, but blur also doesn't work. Apparently, the problem lies on `focus`. See the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use blur event instead of focusout.

Comment: Thanks, but blur also doesn't work. Apparently, the problem lies on `focus`. See the edit.