# Scrollbar firing focusout event in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, focusout

So I have a drop down menu that closes on focusout.
my problem is that in ie when you click on the drop down div's scrollbar, the focusout event fires and the menu closes...
I've tried creating a flag on click but the focusout event fires before the click event does so the flag's no good...
what can i do?

```
$("input#" + selname + "i").focusout(function(){
    $("ul#" + selname + "ul").slideUp(500);
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809388/jquery-focus-and-focusout-conflict-in-ie ?

Comment: @bhantol yes i have and in my case the focusout of the input closes the ul. i've added some code to the question for clarification.

Comment: No space character before '"i"'

Comment: Quickest way I or others can help in this case is if there was a plnkr or something that reproduced the problem. What is the version of IE ?

Comment: @bhantol there isn't supposed to be a space there.. This probably happens in all versions but i'm testing in 11

Comment: Is `ul` the element as in un-ordered list or just any string that makeup the ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if (!$("div." + selname + "wrapper").is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && ($("div." + selname + "wrapper").has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        && (e.target != $("ul#" + selname + "ul").get(0))) // nor the scrollbar
    {
        $("ul#" + selname + "ul").slideUp(500);
        $("input[name=" + selname + "]").val(propvalarray[simplifyString($("input#" + selname + "i").val())].toUpperCase());
        checkProp();
    }
});
```

credit goes to @kurkula